# How to use Couchbase 3.0+ for tests in Travis

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, couchbase, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I need to know how to make couchbase 3.0.+ work in a Travis context.

I have been able to start a Couchbase 2.0 on a Travis context but the 3.0.+ does not seem to actually start (the service daemon on linux says it is started but netstat does not find the web console on port 8091 but the bucket interface is running on 8092, the java-sdk cannot use it).

Here is the script I have tried using in my .travis.yml

```
before_install:
- sudo wget -O/etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase-ubuntu1204.list
- sudo wget http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key && sudo cat couchbase.key
  | sudo apt-key add -
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install libcouchbase2 libcouchbase-dev
- sudo wget http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/3.0.2/couchbase-server-enterprise_3.0.2-ubuntu12.04_amd64.deb
- sudo dpkg -i couchbase-server-enterprise_3.0.2-ubuntu12.04_amd64.deb
- sudo service couchbase-server restart
- /opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-cli cluster-init -c 127.0.0.1:8091 --cluster-username=Administrator --cluster-password=password --cluster-ramsize=512
```

PS: I know Travis instances are only 3GB but the couchbase doc do mention that it can run on 1GB ... I have not been able to find instructions on how to achieve that.

Comment: See https://github.com/couchbase/CouchbaseMock - though this is only Couchbase 2.0 compatible - and if you've managed with Couchbase 2.0, better stick with that. The mock recently gained full support for views - so that might help you a bit.

Comment: I have tried that. I need to test against 3.0. We are already able to deploy 2.0 on travis and we are doing that for now